# C# WPF Conditional event firing

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'd like to have some info regarding the possibility to fire a wpf event only when matching a certain condition.

I explain a bit my situation.

1. I've got 4 textboxes which have to meet a ValidationRule (example being a decimal value between 0 and 100) and if this condition is met the KeyDown event is to be fired.
2. Can I also make it so that the only key for which it's fired is the enter key? so that I don't have to check it in the event code

Can't provide code as I don't know if it's even possible.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Hi I'm back at this again. This is the window

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <vc:StringToDoubleConverter Format="N2" x:Key="stringToDoubleConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox  Width="100" Margin="10" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxInError}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="TextBox.Value" Converter="{StaticResource stringToDoubleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <vr:RegexValidationRule Rule="^\d+,?\d{0,2}$" ErrorMessage="Can have up to 2 decimal digit"/>
                        <vr:DoubleRangeValidationRule Min="0" Max="100"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

This is the main window class

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }

        MainWindowViewModel ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //How can I acces the ValidationResult from here? Since evaluating it again is unneccessary work
            if (e.Key = Key.Enter /*&& Check validation result*/) 
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the MainWindowViewModel class

```
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public TextBoxViewModels<double> TextBox { get; } = new TextBoxViewModels<double>();
    }
```

This is the TextBoxViewModel class

```
    public class TextBoxViewModels<T> : BaseViewModel
    {
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _Value;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!_Value.Equals(value))
                {
                    _Value = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsEnabled;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_IsEnabled != value)
                {
                    _IsEnabled = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabled));
                }
            }
        }
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_IsVisible != value)
                {
                    _IsVisible = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
                }
            }
        }

        private T _Value;
        private bool _IsEnabled;
        private bool _IsVisible;
    }
```

This is the BaseViewModel class

```
    public class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This is the ValueConverter class

```
    public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public string Format { get; set; } = "";
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                return Format != String.Empty ? ((double)value).ToString(Format) : ((double)value).ToString();
            }
            return "";
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                return Double.Parse((string)value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the ValidationRule class

```
    public class DoubleRangeValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public double Min { get; set; } = Double.MinValue;
        public double Max { get; set; } = Double.MaxValue;
        public bool IncludeExtremes { get; set; } = true;
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            double number = 0;
            try
            {
                if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                {
                    number = Double.Parse((string)value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, $"Illegal characters or {ex.Message}");
            }
            if (IncludeExtremes)
            {
                if (number < Min || number > Max)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, $"Please enter a value in the range: {Min} - {Max}, including extremes");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (number <= Min || number >= Max)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, $"Please enter a value in the range: {Min} - {Max}, excluding extremes");
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously need to define and evaluate the condition somewhere.

You could either do this in the event handler or before you raise the event assuming you have control over the code that actually raises the event.

If you are referring to the built-in `KeyDown` event, you don't control when this one is raised so then you should check your condition in the handler.

**Edit:**

You could use the `Validation.GetErrors` method to check whether there are any validation errors in the event handler:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        if (Validation.GetErrors((TextBox)sender).Count > 0)
        {
            //has validation error(s)...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the built-in event of WPF controls, so I have to check the pressed key in the handler, do I have somehow access to the ValidationResult from code? couse it'll come in handy to know when the textbox has valid text

Comment: Where and how are you handling the event? And how is this related to any validation rule?

Comment: I postetd an answer with all of my code, can you help me

Comment: Why do you even need a `ValidationRule` when you handle the `KeyDown` event? The unnecessary part seems to be the `ValidationRule`. Invoke your validation logic from the event handler?

Comment: 'Couse the UI has a Validation, and my Text property is bound with a value converter, so I want to know when the user presses Enter in the text box and the value is actually valid, since I can't prevent the user from pressing enter with invalid text and I need the exact value wich is typed in.
The validation rule is needed couse so I don't have to notify the error from code

Comment: @DanielMartin: Please see my edit answer for an example of how you could check whether there are any validation errors in the event handler.

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I wanted didn't know about the Validations.GetErrors() nor the Validations.GetHasErrors()